# How to get connection URL?

Tags: teradata

I am work on Teradata using SQL Assistant. I want to connect to the database using JDBC but I need to get the connection URL.

Where can I find it at
 SQL Assistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Assistant doesn't support JDBC connections, just ODBC and .NET

For JDBC you might use Teradata Studio Express instead:

http://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-studio-express-14-10-01-now-available

Comment: Thank you. I do not plan to use JDBC and SQL assistant. I am not allowed to install 'studio'. Is there any way I could get the **connection url** either through **cmd** or any other way?

Comment: This is what i have been trying to use so far `String connurl="jdbc:teradata:///TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8jdbc:teradata:///TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8";` And this is apparently wrong

Comment: This should work: `jdbc:teradata://TDServer/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8` Do you actually use three slashes?

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo. So my problem is I do not know who is my `TDServer` ? How can I get it from cmd or anywhere else?

Comment: `TDServer` is either the IP-address (the you should add the COP=OFF option) or the logical name of the system (for multi node systems), you have to ask you DBA for it